# Is how does one change HTML ENTITIES to UTF-8?

Tags: php

When the form submits I receive the Greek Letter as `&#932;` however to write it to the MySQL database the Letter needs to be in utf8_general_ci format. In PHP how would the change Be easy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Convert to UTF-8
$greekWord = mb_convert_encoding($greekWord, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');

//Convert to HTML-ENTITIES
$greekWord = mb_convert_encoding($greekWord, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a single function to do that, but you can do it like this:

```
echo htmlentities(html_entity_decode('&#932;'));
```

It also works with longer strings and ignores the non-entity-parts:

```
echo htmlentities(html_entity_decode('bla blubb &#932; hello'));
```